# How to set flexbox direction when i set my page size?

Tags: css, flexbox

I have this box configuration.

```
 _ _ _ _  _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
|       ||      2        |
|   1   ||_ _ _ _ _  _ _ |
|       ||      3        |
|_ _ _ _||_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _|
```

How do I switch to this configuration after decreasing the size of my page?

```
 _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
|       |            |
|   1   |     2      |
|       |            |
|_ _ _ _|_ _ _ _ _ _ |
|           3        |
|_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ |
```

My html code (with box 2 and 3 inside another box):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Flexbox</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app">
            <div class="box blue"></div>
            <div>
                <div class="box red"></div>
                <div class="box green"></div>
            </div>                

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

My css code (i put boxes 2 and 3 inside another box, but i'm trying to do it without this extra box)

```
html, body, #app {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

#app{
    display: flex;
}

.white{
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    flex: column;
}

.box{
    width: 500px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 5px;
}

.red{
    background: #f00;
}
.green{
    background: #0f0;
}
.blue{
    background: #00f;
    height: 400px;
    width: 20%;
}
```

Comment: look into media queries

Comment: Could you provide the CSS rules you're using at the moment?

Comment: I put red and green boxes inside the same box:                                                          html, body, #app {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

#app{
    display: flex;
}

.white{
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    flex: column;
}

.box{
    width: 500px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 5px;
}

.red{
    background: #f00;
}
.green{
    background: #0f0;
}
.blue{
    background: #00f;
    height: 400px;
    width: 20%;
}

Comment: Post your HTML code as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your layout looks like it's split into 3x3 layout so using absolute positioning on the first container and then a margin-left of 33.33% on the container 2 and 3 gets you the first layout.

For the second one just keep using the flexbox layout.

Just change out the width in the media query at which you want it to switch.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  --margin-container: 30px;
}

.container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  position: relative;
}

.container-1 {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 33.33%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.container-2,
.container-3 {
  margin-left: calc(33.33% + var(--margin-container));
  width:calc(66.67% - var(--margin-container));
  height:50%;
}

.container-2 {
  background-color: red;
}

.container-3 {
  background-color: green;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .container-1 {
    position: relative;
    background-color: blue;
    width: 33.33%;
    height: 66.67%;
  }
  .container-2,
  .container-3 {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  .container-2 {
    background-color: red;
    width: 66.67%;
    height: 66.67%;
  }
  .container-3 {
    background-color: green;
    width: 100%;
    height: 33.33%;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="container-1">

    </div>

    <div class="container-2">

    </div>
    <div class="container-3">

    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```